# jQuery RadioButtonList with different names and same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic radio button group. The names and Ids are dynamic. The issue I am having is that I am able to select multiple radio buttons at the same time because the names are different. I need to be able to select only one at a time. I assigned a class to the group and want to be able to select only one using the class name.

Tried this but it's not working

```
$('.rClass').click(function () {
    $('.rClass').prop("checked", false);
    $(this).prop("checked", true);
});
```

but it's not working. Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide a [mre]? It works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/k97f10b8/

Comment: I just checked your fiddle and it is working but I am not sure why it's not working on my end. Under the $(document).ready(function () { }) I have a method called DrawCasesCheckboxList();. This function creates dynamic checkboxes and child radiobuttons (coming from DB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use event delegation on the nearest static ancestor of all the radio inputs.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.rClass', function (){
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a radio button group with jQuery and limit the user to selecting only one radio button at a time, you can use the following code:

```
$('.rClass input[type="radio"]').on('click', function() {
   $('.rClass input[type="radio"]').not(this).removeAttr('checked');
   $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

Comment: the event is not being called. I put in a console.log also to see if it is being called but nothing.

Comment: give your test case code, I mean the html

Comment: <li>
 <input type="checkbox" name="spCasefileSummaries_1" id="spCasefileSummaries_1" idd="1" txt="Pregnancy" class="minor-casefile-info"> <label for="option">Pregnancy</label>
 <ul style="list-style: none; padding-inline: 20px; display: block;" ulparentid="1">
  <li><label><input type="radio" parentid="radiobutton_1" name="minor-casefile-info_5" id="minor-casefile-info_5" class="minor-casefile-info-sub"> Test 1</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="radio" parentid="radiobutton_1" name="minor-casefile-info_6" id="minor-casefile-info_6" class="rClass"> Tst 2</label></li>
 </ul>
</li>

Comment: This is the dynamic code generated. Basically there is a checkbox which when clicked displays the child radio buttons.

Comment: the `rClass` should be in th `<ul>` tag here `<ul style="list-style: none; padding-inline: 20px; display: block;" ulparentid="1" class="rClass">` and change the jq like this
`$('.rClass input[type="radio"]').on('click', function() {
    $('.rClass input[type="radio"]').not(this).removeAttr('checked');
    $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
  });`

Comment: I change also the answer